pytorch matrix multiplication accuracy depends on tensor size
I have the following code where I multiply tensor X by a matrix C. Depending on the size of X and whether C is attached to the computation graph, I get different results when I compare batched multiplication vs looping over each slice of X.
import torch
from torch import nn

for X,C in [(torch.rand(8,  50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32,32))),
            (torch.rand(16, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32,32))),
            (torch.rand(8,  50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32,32)).detach())
            ]:

    #multiply each entry
    A = torch.empty_like(X)
    for t in range(X.shape[1]):
        A[:,t,:] = (C @ X[:,t,:].unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

    #multiply in batch
    A1 = (C @ X.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)
    
    print('equal:', (A1 == A).all().item(), ', close:', torch.allclose(A1, A))

Returns
equal: False , close: False
equal: True , close: True
equal: True , close: True

What's going on? I expect them to be equal in all three cases.
For reference,
import sys, platform
print('OS:', platform.platform())
print('Python:', sys.version)
print('Pytorch:', torch.__version__)

gives:
OS: macOS-14.4.1-arm64-arm-64bit
Python: 3.12.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Dec 23 2023, 08:01:35) [Clang 16.0.6 ]
Pytorch: 2.2.0


different matmul algos are used for different input shapes/memory layouts. different algos do not give bitwise-identical outputs.

This is and has been one of the biggest challenges in the field of computation.
For your case, however, you can just simply use the allclose() function with double() to technically use the double precision (float 64).
Code
import torch
from torch import nn


def _compare(X, C):

    A = torch.empty_like(X)
    for t in range(X.shape[1]):
        A[:, t, :] = (C @ X[:, t, :].unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

    A1 = (C @ X.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

    equal = (A1 == A).all().item()
    close = torch.allclose(A1, A)
    max_diff = (A1 - A).abs().max().item()

    print(f'equal: {equal}, close: {close}, diff: {max_diff:.16f}')


torch.manual_seed(4)

for X, C in [
    (torch.rand(8, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32, 32))),
    (torch.rand(16, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32, 32))),
    (torch.rand(8, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32, 32)).detach())
]:
    _compare(X, C)


Prints
equal: False, close: False, diff: 0.0000023841857910
equal: False, close: False, diff: 0.0000019073486328
equal: True, close: True, diff: 0.0000000000000000

Using double()

You can increase the precision.
You can use double precision, which uses torch.float64. It dramatically slow down the program. But it is a tradeoff between computational time and accuracy. That's your call.

Code
import torch
from torch import nn


def _compare(X, C):
    X, C = X.double(), C.double()

    A = torch.empty_like(X)
    for t in range(X.shape[1]):
        A[:, t, :] = (C @ X[:, t, :].unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

    A1 = (C @ X.unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1)

    equal = (A1 == A).all().item()
    close = torch.allclose(A1, A)
    max_diff = (A1 - A).abs().max().item()

    print(f'equal: {equal}, close: {close}, diff: {max_diff:.32f}')


torch.manual_seed(4)

for X, C in [
    (torch.rand(8, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32, 32))),
    (torch.rand(16, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32, 32))),
    (torch.rand(8, 50, 32), nn.Parameter(torch.randn(32, 32)).detach())
]:
    _compare(X, C)


Prints
equal: False, close: True, diff: 0.00000000000000266453525910037570
equal: True, close: True, diff: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000
equal: True, close: True, diff: 0.00000000000000000000000000000000

Note

Torch uses torch.float32 or "single precision" by default, which is not precise enough for your comparison.

If you want to know the details of how these computations are performed, there are resources. For short versions, see these 1, 2, 3.

Floating point arithmetic.



"How can I know that there doesn't exist some other inputs that fail the allclose check?"
You can define tolerances, based on the expected precision of your calculations:
torch.allclose(input, other, rtol=1e-06, atol=1e-08, equal_nan=False)


and test it:
import torch


def test_allclose():
    atol, rtol = 1e-06, 1e-08

    a = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=torch.float64)
    b = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype=torch.float64)

    assert torch.allclose(a, b, rtol=rtol, atol=atol), "Tensors are not close!"


test_allclose()

for _ in range(1000):
    a = torch.rand(100, dtype=torch.float64)
    b = a + torch.randn(100, dtype=torch.float64) * 1e-9
    if not torch.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-06, atol=1e-08):
        print("a:", a, "b:", b, "diff:", b - a)
        assert torch.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-06, atol=1e-08), "Random tensors are not close!"

edge_cases = [
    (torch.tensor([1e-10, 1e-20], dtype=torch.float64), torch.tensor([1e-10, 1e-20], dtype=torch.float64)),
    (torch.tensor([1e+10, 1e+20], dtype=torch.float64), torch.tensor([1e+10, 1e+20], dtype=torch.float64)),
    (torch.tensor([0.0, 1.0], dtype=torch.float64), torch.tensor([0.0, 1.0], dtype=torch.float64))
]

for a, b in edge_cases:
    assert torch.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-06, atol=1e-08), "Edge case tensors are not close!"

print("Test passed.")



Thank you for the answer. But still I don't think I understand. Both in the looped and in the batched version, I'm using float32 precision to perform identical operations. For some inputs I get perfect equality, but for others I get relatively large differences (2e-6 is way bigger than any numerical error I would expect). Why would they be different?
And, even in the case of using doubles I don't get equality, although they are allclose. How can I know that there doesn't exist some other inputs that fail the allclose check?

@dkv: Re “2e-6 is way bigger than any numerical error I would expect”: What error did you expect and how did you calculate it?

@EricPostpischil I would expect numerical error to be on the order magnitude of one bit, so 2^-32 or 10^-10. However, what I would actually expect in this case is an error of zero, because, again, I'm performing identical operations on identical tensors.

@dkv: The default data type of PyTorch is float32. The significand of float32 has 24 bits. That means the smallest possible change to a significand in [1, 2) is 2^−23. You generated random numbers in [0, 1). For those numbers in [½, 1), the smallest possible change is 2^−24, about 6e-8. And if there is any error, there will likely be many, and they will compound or cancel somewhat randomly. An error of 2e-6 is entirely reasonable, and you should not expect errors to be limited to 2^−32 or 10^−10.

@dkv: As for doing “identical” operations, I am unfamiliar with PyTorch and do not know what operations you have requested it to perform. You might consider updating the question with further information to open it up to be with knowledge of floating-point but not PyTorch or Python. However, I expect what is happening is that, while you have requested identical matrix/tensor multiplications, they are not performed with identical individual arithmetic operations…

… All of the additions in a tensor/matrix multiplication are associative in real-number arithmetic, and software implementing the multiplication might order the operations in various ways for efficiency. However, the additions are not associative in floating-point arithmetic. (a+b)+c does not always produce the same result as a+(b+c). The “same” matrix/tensor multiplication performed in different ways may produce different results.
